# Manipulating a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```py
data = {'A' : [1,2,3], 
        'B' : [2,17,17], 
        'C1' : ["C1", np.nan,np.nan],
        'C2' : ["C2", "C2",np.nan]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Dataframe:

```
    A   B   C1  C2
0   1   2   C1  C2
1   2   17  NaN C2
2   3   17  NaN NaN
```

I am creating a variable "C" based on the below logic and code

If any of C's(C1, C2, C3..) has the value "C"= value from C's(C1, C2, C3....).

```py
df['C'] = df.filter(regex='C\d+').stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Result:

```
    A   B   C1  C2  C
0   1   2   C1  C2  C1,C2
1   2   17  NaN C2  C2
2   3   17  NaN NaN NaN
```

Now, I want to perform below logic

If "C" has more than 1 values(say C1, C2) for any row, create a new row and append 2nd value. So I want my output to look like below:

```
    A   B   C1  C2  C
0   1   2   C1  C2  C1
0   1   2   C1  C2  C2
1   2   17  NaN C2  C2
2   3   17  NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: why has the first row `C1`?

Comment: Because perviously the vaue of C was C1,C2, now I want to have row for each C1 and C2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it by use `explode` then `concat`

```
s=df.filter(regex='C\d+').stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list).explode().to_frame('C').join(df)
s=pd.concat([s,df[~df.index.isin(s.index)]],axis=0,join='outer',ignore_index=True,sort=False)
s
Out[62]: 
     C  A   B   C1   C2
0   C1  1   2   C1   C2
1   C2  1   2   C1   C2
2   C2  2  17  NaN   C2
3  NaN  3  17  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I am getting ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'``` error

Comment: @ShanooS this is after pandas 0.25, please update your pandas

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
 df.merge(df.melt(['A','B'],value_name= 'C').dropna().drop('variable',axis = 1),how = "left")
   A   B   C1   C2    C
0  1   2   C1   C2   C1
1  1   2   C1   C2   C2
2  2  17  NaN   C2   C2
3  3  17  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I don't want to specify ['A','B'], as the dataframe has about 30 vars.

Comment: @Shanoo you can simply replace `['A','B']` with `df.columns[~df.columns.str.match('^C')]` or even `df.columns.str.extract('^([^C])',expand = False).dropna()`

Comment: Ya I can use `df.columns.str.extract('^([^C])',expand = False).dropna()`

Comment: But this doesn't work if we have another column which starts with C, say 'CFG'

Comment: @Shanoo then use `df.columns[~df.columns.str.match('^C\\d+')]`

Comment: @Shanoo `df.columns.str.extract('^([^C]\\D*)',expand = False).dropna()` also works

Answer (score 0):

You can just `df.explode(...)`, try:

```py
#please note I aggregate it into list, not string
df['C'] = df.filter(regex='C\d+').stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)

df=df.explode("C")
```

Outputs:

```py
   A   B   C1   C2    C
0  1   2   C1   C2   C1
0  1   2   C1   C2   C2
1  2  17  NaN   C2   C2
2  3  17  NaN  NaN  NaN
```